# Adicionar objecto validando se ele existe

Tags: python, classes

Estou a criar estes dois métodos em que no primeiro valido a existência de uma viatura a partir do seu nome. No segundo, pretende-se adicionar uma nova viatura, validando primeiramente, se existe uma viatura com um determinado nome, para evitar a duplicação de resultados. Contudo, obtenho sempre o erro descrito.

O que é que posso fazer para que tal não aconteça? Apenas o atributo `preco_base` é mutável

```
def exists_viatura(self, nome):
    for v in self.gestor:
        if v.nome == nome:
            return True
        else:
            print("Não existe nenhuma viatura")

def add_viatura(self, new_v):
    for v in self.gestor:
        new_v = Viatura(new_v.nome, new_v.modelo, new_v.tipo_electrica, new_v.preco_base)
        if g.exists_viatura(new_v.nome):
            print("Já existe uma viatura com esse nome")
    self.gestor.append(new_v)
```

Erro:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:/Users/sandr/PycharmProjects/projecto/Classes_Projecto.py", line 189, in add_viatura
    new_v = Viatura(new_v.nome, new_v.modelo, new_v.tipo_electrica, new_v.preco_base)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'nome'
```

Comment: O que diz no erro é que o parâmetro new_v é uma string e portanto não tem atributos.

Comment: Ok, e como é que posso referir-me ao objecto Viatura e fazer com que seja inserido na lista?

Comment: Creio que para ver se já existe é só fazer assim: `existe = new_v in self.gestor`, isso vai retornar False caso não exista a viatura na lista `gestor`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Em Python pra verificar se um objeto existe em uma lista é bem simples. Creio que no seu código ficaria assim:

```
def add_viatura(self, new_v):
    # verifica se existe a viatura na lista 'gestor'
    viatura_existe = new_v in self.gestor
    if viatura_existe:
        print("Já existe uma viatura com esse nome")
    else:
        self.gestor.append(new_v)
```

Comment: Agora tenho um outro problema (estou a tentar construir um projeto a nível académico com programação básica em pyhton). Quando um user aluga uma viatura, é criado um objceto em memória enquanto o Rental estiver ativo. Este objeto tem como atributos o tempo de início do aluguer, o nickname do user, nome da viatura e preço por hora. Inicialmente, criei apenas uma classe. Mas será melhor criar uma classe auxiliar para definir os métodos a usar para iniciar os Rentals?

Comment: Acho que se você criar essa classe auxiliar o código ficaria mais organizado e também tornaria a manutenção mais simples